# Trigger Flex Piechart Item click event when a Datagrid Item is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, charts, flex3

Is it possible to trigger Flex Piechart Item click event when a Datagrid Item is clicked.
If so can anyone give some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Found the solution after some google search,
Tnks for the comments by Neeraj & Nate.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.charts.*;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.graphics.GradientEntry;
        import mx.graphics.LinearGradient;

        [Bindable]
        public var explodingArray:Array = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

        private function explodeSlice(e:ListEvent):void{
            explodingArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
            explodingArray[e.rowIndex]=0.1; 
            pie1.series[0].perWedgeExplodeRadius = explodingArray;
            expenses2.refresh();
        }       

        [Bindable]
        public var expenses2:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Tissues: "Large Intestine", TissueCount: 149},
            {Tissues: "Lung", TissueCount: 127},            
            {Tissues: "Pancreas", TissueCount: 84},
            {Tissues: "Biliary Tract", TissueCount: 58},
            {Tissues: "Haematopoietic and Lymphoid tissue", TissueCount: 20}
        ]);     

    ]]></mx:Script>



    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{expenses2}" editable="false" itemClick="explodeSlice(event)" >
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="TissueCount" headerText="Tissues Count"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Tissues" headerText="Tissues"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

    <mx:SeriesInterpolate id="interpolate" duration="1000"/>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Panel title="Exploding Pie Chart (animated)">
            <mx:PieChart id="pie1" dataProvider="{expenses2}" showDataTips="true" selectionMode="single">
                <mx:series>
                    <mx:PieSeries field="TissueCount" nameField="Tissues" perWedgeExplodeRadius="{explodingArray}" showDataEffect="interpolate"/>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:PieChart>
            <mx:Legend dataProvider="{pie1}"/>
        </mx:Panel>
    </mx:HBox>  

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it a little differently then trying to raise an event on the PieChart.  I would try to encapsulate your pie chart logic into a new function

If you have an event on the pie chart like this:

```
    private function PieChartClick(event:ItemEvent):void{
       DoPieChartClick();
    }

    private function DoPieChartClick():void{
       var selectedItem = picChart.SelectedItem;
       //do the rest of your logic
    }

    private function DataGridClick(event:ItemEvent):void{
        //do your datagrid stuff
        DoPieChartClick(); //This would be like you clicked on the pie chart.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to trigger an itemClick event whenever a datagrid or any other element is clicked.What is important here is that the --index-- of the item in the datagrid should be a function of the --index-- of the item in the piechart.

Any chart has a "series" element, and any "series" element has "items" array in it.
You can trigger a hover/click on this "item" using the flex triggering mechanism.